# javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with Spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `Category` and `Course`. They are associated by `@ManyToMany`.

```
  public class Course {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
        private int courseId;
        @NotBlank(message = "Add the course's title!")
        private String title;
    
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Category> categories;
}

public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int categoryId;
    @NotBlank(message = "category's name must be not empty!")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name="course_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private Set<Course> courses;
```

When I download one category I want to download all its courses as well ( without `fetchType.EAGER` because I don't want to get courses while downloading all categories ). This is my overriden query in `CategoryRepository` (JpaRepository):

```
    @Override
    @Query("SELECT cat FROM Category cat JOIN FETCH cat.courses")
    Optional<Category> findById(Integer id);
```

Since I want to send my client data from two tables, I have created a DTO:

```
public class CategoryAndCourses {
    private Category category;
    private List<Course> courses;

    public CategoryAndCourses(Category category, List<Course> courses) {
        this.category = category;
        this.courses = courses;
    }
```

And there is a place where I actually send both the courses and the category by DTO:

```
public CategoryAndCourses getCourses(int id) {
        var category = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No category with given id"));
            var result = new CategoryAndCourses(category, new ArrayList<>(category.getCourses()));
        return result;
    }
```

With such a code I get this error:
`javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 8`
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: you have a query returnin more than 1 result and your code is defined as expecting a single result.

Aren't you missing a `WHERE` on the `id` on the following query?

```java
@Query("SELECT cat FROM Category cat JOIN FETCH cat.courses")
Optional<Category> findById(Integer id);
```

Comment: LOL, I can't believe I didn't notice it. Fortunately, you are more observant. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

user List<> in fetching more than one item instead of Optional.
Also check your @Query() at the repository; eg

#####List findById(Integer id);#####

Comment: The question you responded to already had a correct answer. Furthermore, while your suggestion could remove the error it does not match the author's intention, so your answer is incorrect.